# Авторизация SOAP клиента на C# по протоколу https

Tags: c#, авторизация, 1с, soap

Здраствуйте, есть soap сервис (1С), добавил его как service reverence, всё сгенерировалось, но при авторизации выдаёт ошибку

```
Запрос HTTP не разрешен для схемы аутентификации клиента "Anonymous". От сервера получен заголовок аутентификации "Basic realm="1C:Enterprise 8.3"".
```

Везде рекомендуют добавить строки указывающие протакол HTTP и авторизацию Basic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495903/calling-a-web-service-that-requires-basic-http-authentication-from-wcf-client
но при добавлении подобного конфига в web.config:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicAuth">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

возникает ошибка:
Аттрибут "mode" не разрешён. и элемент security имеет недопустимый дочерний элемент "transport".
Собственно вопрос, как теперь в 2016 году, в Visual Studio Community Edition для ASP MVC приложения это сделать. Какие должны быть параметры?

Пример web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="ScanStoreEntities" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="MembershipConnection" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="StorePath" value="" />
    <add key="IronManPath" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="1048575" maxRequestLength="1048575" executionTimeout="3600" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" name="PKB_AUTH" />
    </authentication>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="MembershipConnection" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="2097151" maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HKDSoapBinding" />

      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="HKDSoap12Binding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />

          <httpTransport />
        </binding>

      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://172.16.0.3/Test_BIT/ws/hkd.1cws" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="HKDSoapBinding" contract="ServiceReference1C.HKDPortType"
        name="HKDSoap" />
      <endpoint address="http://172.16.0.3/Test_BIT/ws/hkd.1cws" binding="customBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="HKDSoap12Binding" contract="ServiceReference1C.HKDPortType"
        name="HKDSoap12" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Очень странно, этот способ должен работать. Можете добавить в вопрос web.config полностью?

Comment: Добавил web.config

Comment: с customBinding тоже не работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй кодом

```
BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("http://172.16.0.3/Test_BIT/ws/hkd.1cws");
restcoachPortTypeClient Service = new restcoachPortTypeClient(myBinding, ea); 
Service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = Login;
Service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Password;
```

Второй вариант  это использовать `OperationContextScope`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254618/wcf-rest-basic-authentication-not-able-to-set-authorization-header

```
using (new OperationContextScope((IClientChannel)client))
{
   HttpRequestMessageProperty requestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
   string credentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", _username, _password);
   requestProperty.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("Basic {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials)));
   OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestProperty;
   data = client.GetData1();
}
```

По умолчанию для `ToBase64String` используется `ASCII`, что для руских логинов неправильно кодирует.

Comment: спасибо, создав настройки Security в коде, а не в конфиге проблема исчезла

Comment: В 1С HttpClientCredentialType.Basic без вариантов, а вот адрес сервиса можно брать из конфиг файла

Comment: У автора была проблема с customBinding, а вы вместо ее решения предложили ему перейти на BasicHttpBinding...

Comment: В 1С только BasicHttpBinding, плюс решение проблемы с кириллицей в логин пароле

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендация добавлять тэг `security` верна только для стандартных привязок. При использовании пользовательской привязки (customBinding) настройки транспорта надо прописывать непосредственно в транспортном элементе:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding>
        <textMessageEncoding />
        <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```